# Cannot re-enable Bitlocker

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, grub2

I've installed a fresh Windows 10 in a partition on my system, enabling bitlocker. Then I booted Linux from the other partition and overwrote the master boot record with Grub so I could boot Linux and Windows. I also removed an unused NTFS partition, hoping to use it as a shared space between Windows and Linux (don't do it -- Bitlocker needs a NTFS System partition to store the unencrypted boot sector, much like a `/boot` directory on Linux).

However, upon restart Windows complained that "something had changed" on my system and asked me for the BitLocker recovery key. As this kept happening I disabled bitlocker with the idea of re-enabling it later, hoping it would reset itself.

Bitlocker's error was:

> "An Error Occurred The System cannot find the file specified".

I've tried re-creating the NTFS partition, but it failed to boot. I fixed the boot process by starting from a Windows installer from USB and using `bootrec`, the restarting again and using the 'fix the startup' option. However Bitlocker still refused to start. This is related to the error

> "The bitlocker Drive Preparation Tool could not find a target system drive. You may need to manually prepare your drive for BitLocker."

There is an interesting description of the process [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/933246/description-of-the-bitlocker-drive-preparation-tool) with a helpful graph

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple:

1. Open an elevated command prompt (search, `cmd`, right click and 'Run as administrator')
2. Go to  `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery\`
3. Rename the file `ReAgent.xml`:

   ```
   ren ReAgent.xml ReAgent.old
   ```
4. Start Bitlocker

I've spotted the file [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/51947c62-dbcb-4613-b10d-707ff8b61d0d/bitlocker-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified?forum=w8itprosecurity) but all solutions listed are more complicated.

Comment: Worked for me too. My issue started when I tried to re-enable BitLocker after I converted my partitions from MBR to GPT - using [MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt), which complained about `ReAgent.xml` as well.

Comment: The fields in the new ReAgent.xml all seem to have been blanked (id/offset/state 0, guid {000...}, path ""), but that seems to be good enough for BitLocker...