# Bitlocker can’t encrypt a fixed drive. “The system cannot find the file specified”

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I’ve been stumped by this problem. Here’s the computer’s configuration:

- Intel i5 CPU
- ASRock H97 Motherboard (no TPM)
- 1 x Samsung SSD for boot (Bitlocker encrypted with USB key). Formatted with NTFS
- 2 x Seagate HDD mirrored using Storage Spaces. Formatted with ReFS
- Windows 10 Pro 20H2

Every time I try to encrypt drive D:, I get the error “BitLocker Drive Encryption Error”. “can’t encrypt the drive”. “The system cannot find the file specified”.

One thing I found strange is that I’ve had drive C: BitLocker encrypted for some time and also had a fixed drive encrypted the same way before. Since I added the two Seagate drives, I haven’t been able to encrypt any other fixed drives.

I’ve also tried to rename ReAgent.XML as recommended here and that didn’t help: [Cannot re-enable Bitlocker](https://superuser.com/questions/1172548/cannot-re-enable-bitlocker)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on when I went to view my System Restore settings. When I was exploring the ReFS volume settings, I inadvertently set Windows 10 in a Preinstallation Environment (Windows PE) and several features were not working correctly.

To fix:

1. Make sure that you do not have this registry key entry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MiniNT`. If the key is present, delete it.
2. Run `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` in an elevated command prompt
3. After the checks are done, run `sfc /scannow` to make sure all the system files are in good order.

After that, BitLocker will be operational once again for system drives and fixed drives.